# Help with Parsing Multiline and Tool suggestions:

Tags: regex

Edit: So here is a sample of what I have after using BareGrep. The txt doc has about 1000 questions I've created over the years. I've removed the exact answers but I need a tool and syntax to remove the explanations. I use Mac OS 10 and Windows 7/XP.

QUESTION 19:

Why must you blah and blah?

A. So you can blah.

B. So you can blah.

C. So you can blah.

D. So you can blah.

The reason the answer is blah is blah.

QUESTION 20:

When should you blah blah?

A. When you can blah.

B. Where you can blah.

C. Blah you can blah.

D. All of the blah.

The reason the answer is not blah is blah.

Comment: With what tool are you doing this?

Comment: Well I was using BareGrep but it's not going to work because it only does line by line matches. I would be welcome to any suggestions for what to use, either OS 10 or Win7 compatible that's easy to use. BareGrep got me a step further though in pulling out the Answers, but I'm left with the explanations. I'll repost where I'm at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex for Perl:

```
/QUESTION(.+?)Answer/s
```